# How to configure nginx to redirect to same app from multiple ports?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a node.js app and I am running nginx as a reverse proxy server. I want to access the same app through multiple ways.

Let the ip address of machine be `12.16.12.113`. 
Then I want the same app to be accessible through:

1. `12.16.12.113:3000`
2. `test.example.com`

I have 2 Configuration files for nginx in `sites-available` directory:

**file1:**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**file2:**

```
server {
    listen 3000;

    server_name default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I link both the files in `sites-enabled` directory, then only the app is accessible only through `12.16.12.113:3000`. If I remove **file2**, then it is accessible through `test.example.com`.

But I want both the methods to work.

**Edit 1:**
Based on suggestion from [this](https://superuser.com/a/571892) answer, I did the following test:

[image]

It appears that nginx is not listening to port 80. Why is this happening?

Comment: You should not have both your app *and* `nginx` listening on port 3000.

Comment: But `12.16.12.113:3000` is working when both the files are there.

Comment: It is not obvious who is accepting the connection to `12.16.12.113:3000`. Is it `nginx` or is it the NodeJS app? Either way, why make your configuration deliberately ambiguous?

Comment: @RichardSmith I have made an edit. can you now help?

Comment: Is there anything in the error log? Does the configuration pass the `nginx -T` test?

Answer (score 1):

The are few ways to achieve that.

1. You can make your Node app listen on 12.16.12.113:3000 instead of on localhost:3000 and then you will need nginx only for port 80.
2. You can make your Node app listen on localhost:3000 (but only on localhost) and then proxy 12.16.12.113:3000 and port 80 by nginx.
3. You can make your Node app listen on localhost:4000 or 0.0.0.0:4000 on any interface and use nginx to proxy requests to port 80 and 3000.

But you will not be able to make them both listen on the same port and the same interface without problems.

This is the only advice that could be given considering the fact that you didn't include any code example of how your Node app is binding to the ports, which would be the only relevant information here.